# How to make navbar disappear when scrolling?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, navbar

I want to make it so when a user is scrolling, the expanded navbar in smaller view will disappear. Here's what it looks like:

[image: navigation bar]

When the user scrolls, I want that to collapse.

https://jsfiddle.net/2pzx0fqy/

Ignore the broken images, how can I make it so the navbar disappears? Basically, how I'm toggling the navbar right now is using max-height and transition. So when the user scrolls, how can I make it so that it'll collapse the navbar but also the user can click it again?

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "nav.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class = "navigationBar">
    <img src = "https://i.imgur.com/nfbKl0W.png" class = "menuIcon">
    <ul class = "linkBar">

      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> Skills</li>
      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> About</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> Services</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Miscellaneous</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section class = "title">

    <img src = "me.jpg" class = "me">

    <h1 class = "top-name"></h1>
    <h2 class = "top-subtitle">Student - Web Developer - Tutor/Educator</h2>
  </section>

  <section class = "skills">

    <h1 class = "head-title">Skills</h1>

    <div class = "skill-icons">

      <img src = "bigicons/java.png" id = "java">
      <img src = "bigicons/c.png">
      <img src = "bigicons/html.png">
      <img src = "bigicons/js.png">
      <img src = "bigicons/css.png">
      <img src = "bigicons/git.png">

    </div>

    <div class = "modal" id = "modal">
      <div class = "modal-content" id = "lol">

        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>This is a Modal</p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section class = "about">

    <h1 class = "head-title">About</h1>
    <article class = "about-article">

    </article>

  </section>

  <section class = "contact">
    <article>
    Interested in collaborating or just want to get to know me more? Lucky for you, there are several ways you can reach out to me.
    </article>
    <article>

    </article>
  </section>

    <script>

    $('.menuIcon').on('click', function() {
      $('nav ul').toggleClass('show');

    });

    $(function() {

      $(document).on("mousewheel", function() {

        $('nav ul').toggleClass('hide');

      });
    });

    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    var jBtn = document.getElementById('java');
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    jBtn.onclick = function() {

      modal.style.display = "block";

    }

    span.onclick = function ()
    {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter|Dosis|Fira+Sans|Nunito|Oxygen');
body
{
  background-color: #598392;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Bitter', 'Asap', sans-serif;

}

.menuIcon
{
  padding:20px;
  display:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: transform: 0.5s;
}

.navigationBar
{
  background-color: #2E86AB;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
.title
{
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #F7C174;
  padding-top:100px;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-name
{
  font-size:75px;
  position: relative;
  top:-60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-subtitle
{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top:-80px;
}
.navigationBar li
{
  padding:20px;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

a
{
  color: #EFF6E0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover
{
  color: #AEC3B0;
}
nav ul
{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.title h1
{
  padding: 75px 0 0 20px;
}
.title article
{
  padding: 20px;
}


.me
{
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}


.skills
{
  background-color: #FFEECF;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.skill-icons
{

  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;

}
.skill-icons > img
{
  padding: 50px;
  height:128px;
  width:128px;

}

.head-title
{
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.about
{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F7C174;
}
.about-article
{
  padding: 50px;
}

.contact
{
  background-color: #FFEECF
}

/* Modal Stuff */

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.show
{
  display:block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
  .menuIcon
  {
    display:block;
  }

  .navigationBar li
  {
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  nav ul
  {
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0px;

  }


  .show
  {
    max-height: 250px;

  }

  .hide
  {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  .title article
  {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .skill-icons > img
  {
    padding: 20px;
    height:30%;
    width:30%;
  }

}
/*
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
{
  nav ul
  {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
*/
```

Comment: might be that this library will help you: https://github.com/negomi/scrollaway

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your javaScript:

When you scroll down, it'll fade away. When the user scrolls back up, it fades back in.

If this isn't exactly what you want, let me know.

EDIT: Per posters request, I have updated javaScript to make it so that no matter where you scroll up, it will fade back in.

```js
var mywindow = $(window);
var mypos = mywindow.scrollTop();
var up = false;
var newscroll;
mywindow.scroll(function () {
    newscroll = mywindow.scrollTop();
    if (newscroll > mypos && !up) {
        $('.navigationBar').stop().fadeOut();
        up = !up;
        console.log(up);
    } else if(newscroll < mypos && up) {
        $('.navigationBar').stop().fadeIn();
        up = !up;
    }
    mypos = newscroll;
});
```

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Asap');
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Bitter|Dosis|Fira+Sans|Nunito|Oxygen');
body
{
  background-color: #598392;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: 'Bitter', 'Asap', sans-serif;

}

.menuIcon
{
  padding:20px;
  display:none;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition: transform: 0.5s;
}

.navigationBar
{
  background-color: #2E86AB;
  width:100%;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:fixed;
  z-index: 1;
}
.title
{
  overflow:hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: #F7C174;
  padding-top:100px;
  align-items: center;
}

.top-name
{
  font-size:75px;
  position: relative;
  top:-60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.top-subtitle
{
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top:-80px;
}
.navigationBar li
{
  padding:20px;
  display: inline;
  list-style-type:none;
  font-size: 22px;
}

a
{
  color: #EFF6E0;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover
{
  color: #AEC3B0;
}
nav ul
{
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 0;
  transition: max-height 1s;
}

.title h1
{
  padding: 75px 0 0 20px;
}
.title article
{
  padding: 20px;
}


.me
{
  width:250px;
  height:250px;
  border-radius: 100%;
}


.skills
{
  background-color: #FFEECF;
  overflow: hidden;
  height:auto;
  padding-bottom: 50px;
}

.skill-icons
{

  display:flex;
  width:100%;
  justify-content:space-around;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  height: auto;

}
.skill-icons > img
{
  padding: 50px;
  height:128px;
  width:128px;

}

.head-title
{
  font-size: 60px;
  text-align: center;
}
.about
{
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #F7C174;
}
.about-article
{
  padding: 50px;
}

.contact
{
  background-color: #FFEECF
}

/* Modal Stuff */

.modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

.modal-content {
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: 15% auto; /* 15% from the top and centered */
    padding: 20px;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 80%; /* Could be more or less, depending on screen size */
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: #aaa;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}


.show
{
  display:block;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 768px)
{
  .menuIcon
  {
    display:block;
  }

  .navigationBar li
  {
    display:block;
    padding: 10px;
    text-align: left;
    margin-left: 30px;
    font-size: 16px;
  }
  nav ul
  {
    max-height: 0;
    padding: 0px;

  }


  .show
  {
    max-height: 250px;

  }

  .hide
  {
    max-height: 0px;
  }
  .title article
  {
    padding: 20px;
  }

  .skill-icons > img
  {
    padding: 20px;
    height:30%;
    width:30%;
  }

}
/*
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px)
{
  nav ul
  {
    display: block !important;
  }
}
*/
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name = "viewport" content = "width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <link rel = "stylesheet" type ="text/css" href = "nav.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <nav class = "navigationBar">
    <img src = "https://i.imgur.com/nfbKl0W.png" class = "menuIcon">
    <ul class = "linkBar">

      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i> Skills</li>
      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-envelope" aria-hidden="true"></i> Contact</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i> About</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#"><i class="fa fa-briefcase" aria-hidden="true"></i> Services</a></li>
      <li><a href = "#">Miscellaneous</a></li>

    </ul>
  </nav>

  <section class = "title">

    <img src = "me.jpg" class = "me">

    <h1 class = "top-name"></h1>
    <h2 class = "top-subtitle">Student - Web Developer - Tutor/Educator</h2>
  </section>

  <section class = "skills">

    <h1 class = "head-title">Skills</h1>

    <div class = "skill-icons">

      <img src = "bigicons/java.png" id = "java">
      <img src = "bigicons/c.png">
      <img src = "bigicons/html.png">
      <img src = "bigicons/js.png">
      <img src = "bigicons/css.png">
      <img src = "bigicons/git.png">

    </div>

    <div class = "modal" id = "modal">
      <div class = "modal-content" id = "lol">

        <span class="close">&times;</span>
        <p>This is a Modal</p>

      </div>
    </div>

  </section>

  <section class = "about">

    <h1 class = "head-title">About</h1>
   
  </section>

  <section class = "contact">
    <article>
    Interested in collaborating or just want to get to know me more? Lucky for you, there are several ways you can reach out to me.
    </article>
    <article>
     
    </article>
  </section>

    <script>

    $('.menuIcon').on('click', function() {
      $('nav ul').toggleClass('show');

    });

    $(function() {

      $(document).on("mousewheel", function() {

        $('nav ul').toggleClass('hide');

      });
    });

    var modal = document.getElementById('modal');
    var jBtn = document.getElementById('java');
    var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];
    jBtn.onclick = function() {

      modal.style.display = "block";

    }

    span.onclick = function ()
    {
      modal.style.display = "none";
    }

    window.onclick = function(event) {
    if (event.target == modal) {
        modal.style.display = "none";
    }
    }

  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi, thank you. It seems like it works, but how can I also make it so when you scroll up the navbar will reappear? I don't want it to just make it reappear when you go to the top of the page.

Comment: @Stuy I've updated the javaScript to accommodate your needs.